# A property of product category

Tags: category-theory

[image]

This property of the product category states that the projections $P$ and $Q$ are "universal" among pairs of functors to $B$ and $C$.

Can someone specify me exactly the sense of that assertion? I have an idea, but it seems to me somewhat trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Universal" here means that it is "terminal", in the sense that any other triple $(\mathbf D, R, T)$ (I employ your notations) admits a *unique* morphism, in a suitable category (exercise: define that "suitable category"), to $(\mathbf B \times \mathbf C, P, Q)$. This is precisely the universal property of the product, and defines it uniquely up to a unique isomorphism. The notion of product as given here in the category $\mathbf{Cat}$ of small categories is the general notion of product given in any category. See for example the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)).

Comment: The "suitable category" I mean is the following: as objects, take triples $(\mathbf D, R, T)$ with $\mathbf D$ category, $R: \mathbf D \to \mathbf B$, $L : \mathbf D \to \mathbf C$. A morphism $(\mathbf D, R, T) \to (\mathbf D', R', T')$ is a functor $F: \mathbf D \to \mathbf D'$ such that $R'F = R$ and $T'F = T$.

Heuristically: what you want is something which projects on both $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf C$. Among all categories which project on $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf C$, you choose the "smallest" one, i.e. the terminal one. This is exactly the product $\mathbf B \times \mathbf C$.

Comment: this is not trivial, so what I had in mind was wrong. Do you mean a category, whose object are all triples given by a category $D$ and two functors to $B$ and $C$, and the object $(B\times C,P,Q)$? The identity morphism on, say, $(D,R,T)$ will be $(id_D,R,T)$? Deducing this from "universal", I think was impossible for me (being novice in the theory), also having in mind the "terminal" concept, and I think it had to be specified in the text. (I have corrected the preceding $B \times C$ in my previous deleted comment)

Comment: So with "you choose the "smallest" one", do you mean that $B\times C$, being terminal, is the category with the minimum "number" of functors from any other (object) category in the suitable one you indicated? The word "universal" (that was the trouble) means so that $B\times C$ is the codomain of *every* other category in the suitable one?

Comment: but that "smallest" I believe may reach also $0$, and the terminal must have always $1$.. ummm :?...

Comment: Moreover, the cited text refers "universal" to $P$ and $Q$, not to $B \times C$, sorry but I have yet some doubt..

Comment: last possibility, then I'll drop .. "smallest" mean that it is the one with less functors that go to B and C, but I can not see why the product should have less .. could not have any more in addition to P and Q?

Comment: Perhaps "smallest" is somewhat misleading... keep "terminal" instead. There is no "minimality" involved in any usual sense. It is just a heuristic interpretation.

Comment: The idea is: among every "thing" which projects over $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf C$, you choose the "best one". You have, actually, two possibilities: choose an *initial* object, or a *terminal* object. Why do you actually choose the terminal one? Because the initial one is quite trivial (exercise).

Comment: ok... I guess the initial object be the null category, so "universal" should affect the "everything" of the mentioned property: It englobes all. Moreover, using "the smallest" you meant "the best one", but I would ask you if this is to be intended only in terms of efficaciousness (i.e. it takes / incorporates *all*) or also in terms of efficiency (at the minimum cost). This time I hope to have hit the bull... if not, please correct me, otherwise tell me, that's right!

Comment: I never pictured universality as "best choice in term of cost effectiveness", actually. A terminal object (and, dually, an initial object) is interesting because every other object maps uniquely to it. If you picture a category as a directed graph (with the possibility of composing arrows), then a terminal object is a "sink" for every other object, and an initial object is a "source". Perhaps this interpretation could be useful? Category theory is very abstract and formal: you can spend a lot of time finding explanations for the definitions you give, and often you don't get a "best" one.

Comment: Infact I could not imagine in which sense we could interpret efficiency. The acceptation is therefore in the literal meaning of "universal": it affects *all*, not only partcular cases.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $B \times C$ is *terminal* among categories equipped with projections on $B$ and $C$: for every category $D$ and every pair of functors $D \to B$, $D \to C$, there exists a unique function $D \to B \times C$ such that the diagram you posted commutes. [For more information.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property).

Comment: yes, but the concept you linked, in the book I am reading, comes after...

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: MacLane... Can you help me? Please look at the doubts I have. In particular I don t understand the meaning of "universal" referred to the two projections, and the meaning of "the smallest" used by Genovese (why the smallest?)